# how to display names of columns that meet a certain criteria

Tags: display, worksheet-function

[image]

I have an excel 2007 document with 4 columns (headings english, maths, physics, result) and 5 rows.

The rows and columns (cells) are filled with letter grades a, b+, b, c, e, d and f.

required:

1. For a particular row if there is no e or d or f i want the 4th corresponding result column to display "pass all"
2. If for a particular row there is e or d or f, then i want heading english or maths or physics be displayed depending on what subject the student failed.
3. That is, if english is e and maths is f then i want "fail english, maths" be displayed
4. What is required is to write a formula to make column e display what it is shown

Comment: This is a little hard to visualize.  Could you edit your question and include a mockup of what the data might look like and the associated results?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a fancier way to do this but here is one solution.  The example in the picture is more generalized than the description so I'll base the solution on that.  You can add or remove columns from the formula as needed.  This would go in E2:

```
    =IF(OR(A2>"c",B2>"c",C2>"c",D2>"c"),"fail "&IF(A2>"c",A$1&" ","")&IF(B2>"c",B$1&" ","")&IF(C2>"c",C$1&" ","")&IF(D2>"c",D$1,""),"pass all")
```

This formula can be copied down column E as needed.

If you wish to pre-populate an arbitrarily large range of cells and have the cells appear as blank until there is data, you can do this by adding an ISBLANK test.  The entire formula, **excluding the equal sign** would go inside this:

```
    =IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",whole_formula_above)
```

Copy this down the column.  This will look at the first cell in the row to see if it is empty.  If so, it will return a null (the two double-quotes with nothing between them), which will display as blank.  Otherwise, it will use the original formula.

Comment: fixer, you have fixed this. thank you very much. but there are minor problems, which i think are due to my not being so clearer. 1. when i copy the formular to empty cells in column for answer it display "pass all". can you fix this as well? God bless you

Comment: Added that to the answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  If it solved your problem, please click the checkmark.